# Can Twilio IVR record a single answer?

Tags: twilio

I'm looking to build an integration with Twilio and here's a brief outline of what I want to do:
1) Prompt the caller with a numeric (verbal FTW) menu of options
- "Press 1 for X, 2 for Y"
2) Prompt the caller to leave a recording
- e.g., "Leave a message and press # or hang up"
3) Access a recording (mp3) of JUST the answer for #2

Thanks

Comment: Can you make your question clear, please because your description is telling somewhat what are you doing but not the exact problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can absolutely do that! In order to do so, you'll need to provide a series of URLs that respond with [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) to tell Twilio what to do with the call.

Firstly, you'll need to set up a Twilio number so that an incoming call is directed to your first webhook URL. You'll need to do this in your [Twilio console](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/incoming).

Then, your first webhook URL needs to produce the menu of options. This is typically called an IVR and we have a couple of tutorials that show you how to build one in depth here: [IVR: Screening and Recording](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/ivr-screening/ruby/rails) and [IVR Phone tree](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/ivr-phone-tree/ruby/rails) (I've linked to the Ruby/Rails versions of the tutorials here, but there are other languages available, just check the [tutorials page](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials)).

Essentially though, you need to use the [`<Say>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say) and [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) verbs from TwiML to read out the options and respond to the results. For example:

```
<Response>
  <Gather numDigits="1" action="/gather_results">
    <Say voice="alice">Dial 1 to leave a message, Dial 2 to hangup</Say>
  </Gather>
</Response>
```

The [action attribute on the `<Gather>` element](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#attributes-action) points to where the caller should be directed once they enter a digit. At that point you need to write something dynamic that extracts the [`Digits` parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#attributes-action-parameters) from the request. If the number responds to the recording action then you can use the [`<Record>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record) verb to record just that answer.

I've written the below as if it were using Sinatra and Ruby, but hopefully it shows how this would be used in any language.

```
def gather_results
  if params["Digits"] == "1"
    "<Response finishOnKey='#'>
       <Say voice="alice">Leave a message and press # or hang up</Say>
       <Record action="/record_results"></Record>
     </Response>"
  else
     # Do something else
  end
end
```

Finally, you need something to get the recording once it is complete. This final URL lives at the endpoint described in the `action` attribute for the `<Record>` verb. This URL will receive [extra parameters that refer to the recording](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record#attributes-action-parameters), including the URL of the recording file itself. You can write any code you like here, either just saving the URL of the recording or downloading the file itself.

Hope this helps, let me know if there's anything that isn't clear.